# Accessing Property Value from Another Class

Tags: c#, class, properties

This seems very basic, but I can't find an answer exactly like what I am looking for.

I have two classes. One class has a public property, where a value is assigned.

From the second class I would like to use the VALUE (22) of the public property (not create a new instance of the property without the value)

Here is code how I imagine it should work (but doesn't). I understand why it doesn't work (because OriginalClass.ID = null). I don't know how to make the equivalent that does work... Any help would be appreciated.

```
public partial class ClassOne
{
    private int iD;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return iD; }
        set
        {
            iD = value;
        }
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        ID = 22;
    }

}

public class ClassTwo
{
    public void MyLocalMethod()
    {
        ClassOne OriginalClass = new ClassOne();
        var LocalID = OriginalClass.ID;  //I want LocalID to equal 22, but 
obviously doesn't
    }
}
```

Comment: You created a new instance of `ClassOne` but never called `MyMethod` which sets the ID property to 22.

Comment: you are both correct. In my attempt to be brief, I inadvertently ignored the code that actually assigns the value. "22" does get assigned to ID properly. I will try to edit my original question...  The difficultly I am having is when I try to get the value from another class.

Comment: @mrjordan if ID=22 in your class, then LocalId will be equal to 22.  So either you never assign the value of ID or you are for some reason asking a completely different question than you should be asking.

Comment: Thanks. That is helpful. I thought it should work like that, but doesn't seem to. I thought creating a new "OriginalClass", gave me the structure without the values. Also, I cannot use "static" in my scenario. Could you post a simple solution similar to mine that works. If I can get one that works I can figure it out. -thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about calling MyMethod() before assigning?

```
public class ClassTwo
{
    public void MyLocalMethod()
    {
        ClassOne OriginalClass = new ClassOne();
        OriginalClass.MyMethod();
        var LocalID = OriginalClass.ID;  //I want LocalID to equal 22, but 
obviously doesn't
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where some additional information on what you're actually trying to do would be helpful.

You have a number of options to make this work

1) You could change class 2 to something like this

```
public class ClassTwo
{
    public void MyLocalMethod()
    {
        ClassOne OriginalClass = new ClassOne();
        OriginalClass.myMethod();
        var LocalID = OriginalClass.ID;
   }
}
```

2) If you're worried about forgetting to call myMethod() after creating OriginalClass you could create a factory method in ClassOne

```
public partial class ClassOne
{
    private int iD;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return iD; }
        set
        {
            iD = value;
        }
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        ID = 22;
    }

    public static ClassOne createWithIdFact()
    {
      var returnValue = new ClassOne();
      returnValue.MyMethod();
      return returnValue;
    }
}
```

This can then be called from class two in the following manner

```
public class ClassTwo
{
    public void MyLocalMethod()
    {
        ClassOne OriginalClass = ClassOne.CreateWithIdFact();
   }
}
```

3) My guess is you don't want all instances of you object to have ID of 22. If you want a unique id for each instance and don't want to have to worry about manually setting them, init the iD variable from a static variable.

```
public partial class ClassOne
{
    private static nexId = 0;
    private int iD;
    public int ID
    {
        get { return iD; }
        set
        {
            iD = value;
        }
    }

    public ClassOne()
    {
      this.iD = nextId++; // not thread safe
    }

    public static ClassOne createWithIdFact()
    {
      var returnValue = new ClassOne();
      return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I will investigate these options and see where I am getting messed up. Thank you all for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. The best way depends on your context and requirements.

The easiest is to call `MyMethod`:

```
ClassOne OriginalClass = new ClassOne();
OriginalClass.MyMethod();
var LocalID = OriginalClass.ID; // Now it's 22
```

Another approach is to set `ID` to 22 in the constructor:

```
public ClassOne() {
    ID = 22;
}

ClassOne OriginalClass = new ClassOne();
var LocalID = OriginalClass.ID; // 22 again!
```

Alternatively, if you are in C# 6, you can directly do this:

```
// You don't need to declare "iD" as a backing field!
public int ID { get; set; } = 22;
```